# Setting up remoting with zend_amf and cairngorm

Tags: apache-flex, remoting, cairngorm, zend-amf

I am using Flex 3.4 and Cairngorm 2.2 and Zend_AMF for server side. I am having problem in setting up RemoteObjects.

I am getting the infamous Channel disconnected error.

```
[RPC Fault faultString="Channel disconnected" faultCode="Client.Error.DeliveryInDoubt" faultDetail="Channel disconnected before an acknowledgement was received"]
```

When I do not use Cairngorm and use a simple RemoteObject in a mxml file, then everything works fine which suggests that there is no error on php side. Can somebody help me out? I am following the tutorial over here:

[DavidTucker.net » Blog Archive » Getting Started with Cairngorm – Part 4](http://archive.davidtucker.net/2007/11/07/cairngorm-part-4/comment-page-2/#comment-3633)

I would appreciate any suggestions.

With kind regards

ShiVik

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your findings ? It would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a follow-up, found out the answer to this using the Charles Proxy Finder.

Regards
ShiVik